# how can I merge dates difference between them one day if the end date is null at a one inteval

Tags: sql-server

Hi please help me to solve this problem

This code will merge all not null dates the difference between them one day at a one interval If a null end date is found, open a new period, how can I merge dates difference between them one day if the end date is null at a one period

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    startDate DATE,
    ENDDate DATE,
    EmpName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    EmpID INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-01-10', '2001-01-20' , 'yanal', 1 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-01-21', '2001-02-10' , 'yanal', 1 )


INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-02-21', '2001-03-10' , 'abd', 2 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-03-11', '2001-03-20' , 'abd', 2  )


INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-04-11', '2001-05-20' , 'raed', 3 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-05-21', '2001-06-10' , 'raed', 3 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-6-11',null, 'raed', 3 )

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT p1.StartDate,
           p1.EndDate,
           p1.EmpName,
           p1.EmpID
    FROM @Test p1
        LEFT JOIN @Test p2
            ON p1.StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, p2.EndDate) 
               AND p1.EmpID = p2.EmpID
    WHERE p1.EndDate IS NULL
          OR p2.StartDate IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p1.StartDate,
           p2.EndDate,
           p1.EmpName,
           p1.EmpID
    FROM CTE p1
        INNER JOIN @Test p2
            ON p1.EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, p2.StartDate)
               AND p1.EmpID = p2.EmpID)


SELECT StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
       EmpName
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StartDate,
         EmpName;
```

OutPut Query

```
StartDate   EndDate      EmpName
2001-02-21  2001-03-20    abd
2001-04-11  2001-06-10    raed
2001-06-11  NULL          raed
2001-01-10  2001-02-10    yanal
```

I need to merge a period employee into a single period

To become outputs

```
StartDate   EndDate      EmpName
2001-02-21  2001-03-20    abd
2001-04-11  NULL          raed
2001-01-10  2001-02-10    yanal
```

thank you

Comment: Which SQL server version are oyu using?

Comment: 12.0.2000.8 (2014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very elegant solution, but it does work. I added one extra CTE.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    startDate DATE,
    ENDDate DATE,
    EmpName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    EmpID INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-01-10', '2001-01-20' , 'yanal', 1 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-01-21', '2001-02-10' , 'yanal', 1 )


INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-02-21', '2001-03-10' , 'abd', 2 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-03-11', '2001-03-20' , 'abd', 2  )


INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-04-11', '2001-05-20' , 'raed', 3 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-05-21', '2001-06-10' , 'raed', 3 )

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES
( '2001-6-11',null, 'raed', 3 )

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;WITH CTE
AS (SELECT p1.StartDate,
           p1.EndDate,
           p1.EmpName,
           p1.EmpID
    FROM @Test p1
        LEFT JOIN @Test p2
            ON p1.StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, p2.EndDate) 
               AND p1.EmpID = p2.EmpID
    WHERE p1.EndDate IS NULL
          OR p2.StartDate IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p1.StartDate,
           p2.EndDate,
           p1.EmpName,
           p1.EmpID
    FROM CTE p1
        INNER JOIN @Test p2
            ON p1.EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, p2.StartDate)
               AND p1.EmpID = p2.EmpID)

, CTE_2 AS 
(
    SELECT StartDate,
         MAX(CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN '29991231' ELSE ENDDate END) AS EndDate,
         EmpName
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY StartDate,
           EmpName
)

SELECT EmpName, 
      MIN (StartDate) AS StartDate,
      CASE WHEN EndDate = '29991231' THEN NULL ELSE EndDate END AS EndDate
FROM CTE_2 
GROUP BY EmpName, CASE WHEN EndDate = '29991231' THEN NULL ELSE EndDate END
ORDER BY EmpName
```